# JavaScript write asyncronous data to clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I want to be able to write custom objects to the clipboard so they can be pasted in other parts of my web application again.

For this, I have the following code:

```js
window.addEventListener('copy', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName == 'BODY') {
        e.preventDefault();

        var clipboardData = e.clipboardData || e.originalEvent.clipboardData;

        getItems().then(function(items) {
            clipboardData.setData('text/plain', '');
            clipboardData.setData('application/items', JSON.stringify(items));
        });
    }
});
```

If I just use `clipboardData.setData` directly in the event function, it works.

The problem is that I can only get my items asynchronously with a promise through `getItems()`.
However, it seems like the browser already expires the permission to edit the clipboard in this other execution "thread".

In Firefox 77.0, I get an error on `clipboardData.setData` when called from within the promise's `then`:
`Error: Modifications are not allowed for this document`.

Is there a way how I can write to the clipboard asynchronously?
If no, what other options do I possibly have? Try to pre-fetch the data and hope it's there whenever the event is triggered?

Comment: Does `getItems()` have a particularly large or regularly changing response? If not, you could make the call after the document is loaded and store the response in a variable (And perhaps hide the copy button until the data exists)

Comment: "Is there a way how I can write to the clipboard asynchronously?"  Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard. But from the example it seems that your async part does not depend on the clipboard data so you could get this data before attaching event listener.

Comment: @DBS `getItems()` is regularly changing, yes.
However, the reference it returns never changes.
I might actually just call `getItems()` once, register the event inside the promise `then` and read from the object in the state it is when I need it.